# bounded type with static method returning String

Tags: java, generics

How do I write something like below for static method, my return type is String.

```
public static String create(T extends Order order)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `public static String create(Order order)`?

Comment: Oops, but can't I write using extends ?

Answer (score 3):

From [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

```
public static <T extends Order > String create(T  order)
```

Answer (score 1):

`public static <T extends Order> String create(T order)`

but as Sweeper wrote above `public static String create(Order order)` is valid too